# `image` is not displaying my matrix in the range I specified

Tags: r, image, plot

I have a 20 * 40 matrix, say `test <- matrix(1,20,40)`, and want to convert it to an image.

If I display it directly:

```
image(test)
```

It is displayed on range `[0,1] * [0,1]`.

[image]

I want to display it on the range `[90,110] * [180,220]` so I do:

```
image(test, xlim = c(90, 110), ylim = c(180, 220))
```

but it doesn't show anything:

[image]

I want to show the image and change the axis range, how can I do that?

Comment: `matrix(1,20,40)` gives you 800 1's in a matrix.  Is this what you wanted? Color 1 is white. The limits you set in your second `image` call are greater than 1.  Try `image( matrix( seq( 1, 800 ), 20, 40 ) )` and see if that gets you on the right path.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't clarify my problem. I want to change the scales on axis before. But I failed in using xlim and ylim, which I always think are used for doing it. Now my problem is solved and I know my error. Anyhow, I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a misunderstanding here. Where the matrix will be plotted is controlled by `x`, `y` argument of `image`, while `xlim` and `ylim` are used to specify where range you are looking at, i.e., where you are zooming in.

If you don't specify `x` and `y` in `image()` and just pass in the matrix `test`, it will take

```
x = seq(0, 1, length = nrow(test))
y = seq(0, 1, length = ncol(test))
```

to proceed. So the matrix is actually plotted on `[0,1] * [0,1]`. If you don't further specify `xlim` and `ylim`, `image()` will take `xlim = range(x)` and `ylim = range(y)`, so you are inspecting where you are plotting. But if you further specify `xlim = c(90, 110)` and `ylim = c(180, 220)`, although the matrix is still in `[0,1] * [0,1]`, you are zooming into `[90, 110] * [180, 220]`, where there is nothing.

The correct way to go is:

```
image(x = 90:110, y = 180:220, z = test)
```

[image]

Comment: Well, thanks for your help. I really misunderstood xlim and ylim. I thought they are used to change the scales on axis before. Now I know how to use them and how to solve my problem.